# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: google-chrome

I came across the following error in chrome for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorde) url.

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Nuvola_apps_kaboodle.svg/16px-Nuvola_apps_kaboodle.svg.png`

I'm able to open the url provided in the error message without any errors.

So, What is the reason for the error?

Comment: I'm intermittently having this issue as well with moment.js. Any ideas yet?

Comment: I'm having this issue with plnkr.co, I've no idea whats causing it though.

Comment: I am having these issue when I try to connect my angular to phpmyadmin any idea?

Comment: @sorter did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue in my website with the file `indexMob.js` since I installed **Avast Antivirus**.

When I disabled the web shield feature its solved the issue.