# Getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for image

Tags: apache, google-chrome

I have same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019808/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-empty-response) asks, but there are no answers there.

URL is http://tradebanq.com/images/linkedin-home-icon.png

it gives **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**.

Can I get a clue on how to fix this problem or where to start debugging from? Is it on server? if so how can I fix it on server?

Apache logs are fine, so are file permissions. File size is 36kb but it never opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was our Wifi Router blocking the urls with words such as Facebook, Linkedin etc. My suggestion for people coming across this problem will be to debug ISP or Router connectivity.