# AJAX - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server

I'm running some javascript which uses a setInterval to trigger an AJAX request and then performs some actions based on the returned output. I'm quite confused with it, because it works perfectly on my home server, but now that I've put it out onto the web, I'm having problems.

The following error appears on Google Chrome:

```
http://www.domain.com/ajax/sound.php 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

The error doesn't occur consistently however. Sometimes the scripts run for several minutes before an error occurs. Sometimes it all breaks down in seconds.

I've already checked the obvious solution - that my server-side script is returning nothing. I did this by commenting out the entire script and having it do nothing but return information. That didn't help.

I have several AJAX requests running from the same page, and all of them eventually return the same error (with their respective pages of code). I've tried isolating the requests and performing them one at a time at a slowed down rate, and have determined that the requests work in a general sense, but as soon as one of them sends an error, they all completely stop working and start sending the same error.

Once the errors occur, I get no response when I try to access any part of my site (even parts with no AJAX). Safari says "...the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again." I've tried this in Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox as well with similar results. Thankfully, the site does come back up after a few minutes of making no AJAX requests.

An example of one of the AJAX requests is as follows:

```
//At the set interval, we create a string for the request:

function alef(){
    string = "a='a'";
    request(sound, "ajax/sound.php", string);
}

//That function fires off an AJAX request:

function request(fix, url, string){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            fix(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(string);
}

//The AJAX request returns a result to be processed by the following function:

function sound(text){
    if(text == "sound"){
        insound.play();
    }
}
```

Presume that my sound.php files says:

```
<?php echo "sound"; ?>
```

It doesn't say only that, but even when it did for testing purposes, I had the same problem.

Any solutions?

Comment: Try it without the query string, also try this `request(sound(), "ajax/sound.php", string);`

Comment: possibly related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019808/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-empty-response

Comment: @Mattigins - With the simplified example I gave that might work, but the page is dynamically creating input for the PHP page, and the PHP page is processing it to determine whether or not it ought to return "sound". No query string means no function.

Comment: @James - I looked at that and all the answers that seemed to have the same error. Whether they are related I can't really say, but most of them are unanswered anyway...

Comment: @Truth do a simple test with simple php like your example.

Comment: @Truth Did you try other browsers, like firefox, safari, opera?

Comment: @Mattigins - I tried both options you gave. The first crashed as always. The second is not valid code and crashed immediately.

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul - I used Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Explorer. All crashed. I didn't record individual error codes for each one.

Comment: Test your sound.php code with GET PARAMETERS and see if it works

Comment: I've determined that this is a server issue and not a design issue. Running the same script on another server worked just fine. I'm not server-sharp enough to know exactly what the difference is between the two. Perhaps I'm just making more AJAX requests than the first server could handle? In any case, I've got this up and running with no problem now.