# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php

Hi I have the following

```
$this->xmlapi->api1_query($cPanelUser, 'SubDomain', 'addsubdomain', array($subDomain,$rootDomain,0,0, $dir));
$this->xmlapi->api1_query($cPanelUser, "Mysql", "adduser", array($databaseuser, $databasepass));
$this->xmlapi->api1_query($cPanelUser, "Mysql", "adddb", array($databasename)); 
$this->xmlapi->api1_query($cPanelUser, "Mysql", "adduserdb", array($databasename, $databaseuser, 'all'));
```

everything works fine in firefox but i'm getting an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE page in chrome and IE

I have read about it and i have to try clearing chache according to some people and others recommend releasing my ip but both are out of the question.

All i want to do is allow people to create accounts on the fly. If anyone knows a fix for this or another way of doing the same thing through cPanel api it would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019808/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-empty-response

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find some solution?