# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when console not opened

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, console.log

I am getting `"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"` error for my api calls if console is not opened. However **if console is opened, the api calls work fine**. Angular2 is used on frontend side and NodeJS for backend.Can someone please help?

Comment: check if there are console.logs in your app. Try removing those.

Comment: No errors other than the api failed "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error.

Comment: It's a very strange behavior that seems to come from your environment rather than your code. Can you tell us more about your local environment ? (chrome extension / antivirus etc.)

Comment: I am using ubuntu and I have not installed any extensions like that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be linked to this issue : 
[Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019808/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-empty-response)

For him, the problem came from Avast Antivirus